# Select Slides based on keywords in Powerpoint

Tags: select, powerpoint, keyword

I'm trying to create a macro that will select any slide that contains a keyword in the title, but not getting anywhere. The ppt includes different frontpages, disclaimers and content slides and the idea is to add keywords to the titles of each slide and get the macro to select and export the selected slides to PDF.

I've got the export part working, but have the enter the slide numbers manually.

I got the code below from a similar question, but can't rewrite it to select the slides instead of presenting the answers as a MsgBox. Can somebody help, please?

```
Sub FindText()
Dim sld As Slide, shp As Shape, list As String, myPhrase As String
myPhrase = InputBox("enter a phrase", "Search for what?")

For Each sld In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.HasTextFrame Then
            If Left(shp.Name, 5) = "Title" Then
                If Not shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Find(FindWhat:=myPhrase) Is Nothing Then
                    If list = "" Then list = sld.Name Else list = list & ", " & sld.Name
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next shp
Next sld
MsgBox list

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, when you save as PDF, the PDF won't include any slides that are hidden, so you can simply hide all the slides first, then UNHIDE any that you want to include in the PDF. While I haven't done this here, you'll want to UNHIDE all the slides again after saving to PDF.

```
    For Each sld In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides

' FIRST, hide the slide:
sld.SlideShowTransition.Hidden = True

        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.HasTextFrame Then
                If Left(shp.Name, 5) = "Title" Then
                    If Not shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Find(FindWhat:=myPhrase) Is Nothing Then

' UNHIDE the slides that contain your keywords
sld.SlideShowTransition.Hidden = False                        
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        
        Next shp
    Next sld
```

Comment: Thank you very much Steve, that did the trick and will save me lots of time in the future!

There was a End If missing, but adding that it worked perfect!

Comment: Arrghhh.  Thanks for catching that. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

My full code, using Steve's solution, if anyone is trying to solve the same problem:

```
Sub SelectedSlidesToPDF()
    
  Dim sld As Slide, shp As Shape, list As String, myPhrase As String

myPhrase = "WhatYouLookFor"

    For Each sld In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides

' FIRST, hide the slide:
sld.SlideShowTransition.Hidden = True

        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.HasTextFrame Then
                If Left(shp.Name, 5) = "Title" Then
                    If Not shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Find(FindWhat:=myPhrase) Is Nothing Then

' UNHIDE the slides that contain your keywords
sld.SlideShowTransition.Hidden = False

                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next shp
Next sld

'EXPORT slides
  ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat ActivePresentation.Path & "\" & "MySelectedSlides " & Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 1), "yyyy-mm") & ".pdf", ppFixedFormatTypePDF, ppFixedFormatIntentPrint, RangeType:=ppShowAll

    
' UNIHDE all slides in presentation
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        sld.SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoFalse
    Next sld

End Sub
```